# What do you qualify an athlete who wasn't drafted into the premier league?

Tags: word-request

When teams draft athletes in certain sports they sometimes already play professionally with people of their countries, sometimes they are semi-professional, and sometimes they are amateur, is there an adjective to identify these players? This is true in the NHL.

For example:

> NHL teams drafted many ___ athletes this year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the sport.  Many professional sports have **"minor league"** teams that (more or less) field professional players who aren't quite good enough to make it into the big leagues, or who need some improvement before they may be ready.

[List of developmental and minor sports leagues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_developmental_and_minor_sports_leagues)

As you can see from this list, officially some are referred to by *class* (Class AAA, Class A, etc.), some are called "rookie" leagues (for new players), and others *independent*, *junior*, *off-season*, and various other terms.  However, "minor league" should be a good all-around term.

Comment: This is a term I only associate with American sports, but then, so too the concept of a draft, by and large.

Answer (score 0):

The simple word is "undrafted".

In the context of your sentence, the sense of "undrafted" is already implied, so nothing more needs to be said:

> NHL teams drafted many athletes this year.

By saying that they have been drafted this year implies that they were previously undrafted (unless I misunderstand how american sport works)